# Using Web Technologies for Flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm an Avid Javascript developer, and am wondering if there's any to use Open web technologies (JS/HTML/CSS) to build a flash game.

After a few Google searches, i've got nothing, so I'm asking here.

Comment: ... Why would you want to do that if you can already build a game in JS ? Are you looking for protection for your files ?

Comment: I'm looking to build a game I want to build in JS for Kongregate.com, but they only take Flash Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is just as "open" as JavaScript. They are both based on [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript). The Flex compiler is fully open-source, and there are a bunch of really great open-source tools for developing with, including my personal favorite IDE; [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Flex and Flash can also use CSS for formatting if you prefer, but there are better options than verbose CSS.

Comment: Thanks, i was aware that Flash was ECMA Script, unfortunatly it's an attempt at what was ES4, not ES5/Strict; But I wasn't aware the compiler from Adobe was Open Source, Thanks.

Comment: The compiler that the Flash IDE uses is not open-source, but the compiler in the Flex SDK (MXMLC) is open-source.

Comment: Sweet Thanks, Looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the Flash game on the web, http://wonderfl.net/ is forkable and editable code that compiles instantly all in your browser, with a pretty vibrant community of flash developers (though I find a lot of the code comments are in Japanese, which I can't unfortunately speak/read). The editor I think defaults to a flash based text editor, but there is an option to use a html/css version instead.

If you want to build an editor like wonderfl.net, you'll need a serverside SWF compiler. I believe [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/) is still the most popular way to do that.

If you just want to build a flash game without buying flash, Eclispse + the Opensource FLEX sdk will do it with some work or notepad/textmate + MTASC.

Comment: I'm looking to compile HTML/CSS/JS into a swf, but thanks for all of the links!